# Duplicates in saving an image to database

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

Saving / Updating the image in the database are only duplicate images of what I saved first

This is for C# Windows Form, i already tried putting some null's on variables

This is my code in saving an image

**private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)**

```
             if (pictureBox1.Image == null)
            {MessageBox.Show("Please insert a picture");}
            else
            {   byte[] img = null;
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(imgloc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                img = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);

                db.sp_saveofficials(Main.userid, img, txtfirstname.Text, textBox1.Text, txtlastname.Text, comboBox2.Text, 
                    dateTimePicker2.Value.Date, dateTimePicker1.Value.Date,login.username);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = db.sp_viewofficials();
                imgloc = null; }
```

I also guess maybe theres something wrong in my picturebox code

**private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)**

```
OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            PictureBox p = sender as PictureBox;
            if (p != null)
            {
                open.Filter = "(*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.png;*.gif;)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp; *.png; *.png;";
                open.Title = "Select a picture";
                if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    imgloc = open.FileName.ToString() ;
                    p.ImageLocation = imgloc;
                }
            }
```

I expected that I can Save different images on the database ,

> All data's I have tried saving in the database has same image as my first saved image

Here is my db.sp_saveofficials code for reference

```
        create proc sp_saveofficials
        @userid int,
        @pic varbinary(max),
        @fname varchar (50),
        @mname varchar (50),
        @lname varchar (50),
        @position varchar (50),
        @startterm  datetime, 
        @endterm  datetime,
        @addedby varchar (50)
        as
        insert into tblbarangayofficials values(@userid,@pic,@fname,@mname,@lname,@position,@startterm,@endterm,@addedby,GETDATE())
```

Comment: There is no you code you shared which is saving images to the database.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the  db.sp_saveofficials method please.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the db.sp_saveofficials is the one saving it to the database it is a stored procedure

Comment: @betelgeuce the variable img in db.sp_saveofficials is stored in database 
"pic varbinary(max)"

Comment: Issue could be with your stored procedure as you say you are "saving \ updating". Perhaps this part of the SP is firing twice and hence  you get duplicates.

Comment: the other fields are fine, only the image duplicates

Comment: If the field is a varbinary and you are talking about one row where the "image duplicates" how does the image "duplicate"....?

Comment: what I mean is when saving data's (new rows), the image duplicates on what I saved first. But other fields works fine

Comment: Check if the stored procedure is executing twice (database profiler), or if there are weird triggers. Consider also editing your question and adding the `sp_saveofficials` code.

Comment: Updated, duplicate image seems happening because of the variables holding the image data  but didn't clear the variable after saving but I cant figure it out

Comment: Clear it manually after the excution of your stored procedure.